# RSpec Code Completion in RubyMine

Tags: rspec, autocomplete, rspec-rails, rubymine, code-completion

Can RubyMine be configured to provide code completion for RSpec?  If so, could you please tell me how?  I did try, unsuccessfully, to find a solution to this question before posting it.  Thank you!

Comment: Follow the instructions here: https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/using-rspec-in-ruby-projects.html [![screenshot with code completion](http://i.stack.imgur.com/usqBK.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/usqBK.png)

Comment: @dug is `require 'rspec'` necessary?